# Digital Rights and Agents talking to humans

Tags: legal, digital-rights

How does the legal question about agents talking to humans via telephone connection work? Recently Google gave a talk about Duplex, where an agent makes a call to a human to schedule a hairdresser.

I wonder if there are any regulations related to this type of scenario, if there are some limitations, if the human needs to know that he is talking to an AI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Googling this throws a lot of debate on this issue of whether the call made to the restaurant for booking was legal or not. I found this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/is-google-duplex-ethical-and-moral-f66a23637640) to put forward a lot of ideas for and against this. So it is for us to decide.

But one thing that I fully agree with you, which should be made into a regulation, is human should know that he/she is talking to a bot. This tweet by [@traviskorte](https://twitter.com/traviskorte/status/993954759932612608) reasons it out why:

`We should make AI sound different from humans for the same reason we put a smelly additive in normally odorless natural gas.`